# Get Firebase token from external API in my test cases

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have written custom nodejs authentication utilising the firebase token based auth module.

I'm trying to setup an automated test suite for the whole auth module in my backend. The APIs require the firebase token, which I have to manually setup down.

I have used below api to verify a custom token, I'm unable to pass the response in all my test files -

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken?key=${API_KEY}
```

Can I automate this process of retrieving the firebase token and passing them directly to my test cases?

Firebase Token generation -

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const FirebaseAccount = require('../../config/test-firebase.json');

Firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: Firebase.credential.cert(FirebaseAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://' + FirebaseAccount['project_id'] + '.firebaseio.com'
});

Firebase.auth().createCustomToken("alice")
.then(async (customToken) => {
    const data = {
        token: customToken,
        returnSecureToken: true
    };

    fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken?key=${API_KEY}', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
        process.env.firebasToken = json.idToken;
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
});
```

Comment: I don't see why wouldn't it work, please share your test cases and any relevant code for us to help you.

Comment: The get request is being processed in a separate node file. While requiring the file in other files I have to wait for the request to be processed. I have added the code.. How should I export the received token?